# How do I work with Google Analytics oAuth in a WebAPI?

Tags: oauth, asp.net-web-api, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am building an extension for open source ASP.NET CMS Umbraco where I want to fetch the analytic's from the user's account once they have authorised via oAuth.

The example MVC 4 snippet over on the Google API .NET wikiw page for oAuth seems to only work with a controller and not a WebAPI controller as far as I can tell, is this right?

```
AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new AppFlowMetaData()).AuthorizeAsync(cancellationToken);
```

The first parameter in the example expects it to be a regular MVC Controller

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis.Auth.Mvc4/OAuth2/Mvc/AuthorizationCodeMvcApp.cs

So my question is really, how do I work with oAuth with a WebAPI in mind, as I want to return stats back from the API as JSON from the WebAPI so I can use a client side library such as AngularJS to bind the JSON returned to the HTML view?

I would love for any ideas, feedback or suggestions on how I could solve this please.

Thanks,
Warren :)

Answer (score 0):

I have looked into your problem and the i have tested the service account solution. It's tricky to setup but when it runs it works.

This is the code I used in a webapi controller :

```
String serviceAccountEmail = "805395301940-cu3nhkuqi4ipa3453o276bar5u2e70lq@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
var cert = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/key.p12");
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(cert, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
    new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
    {
        Scopes = new[] { AnalyticsService.Scope.Analytics }
    }.FromCertificate(certificate));

var service = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential
});

//var ga = service.Data.Ga.Get("ga:31335471", "2013-01-01", "2013-01-31", "ga:visits");

// Not Working Currently in Beta
//var ga = service.Data.Realtime.Get("ga:31335471", "ga:activeVisitors");

var ga = service.Management.Profiles.List("~all", "~all");
return ga.Execute();
```

Comment: Oh and your using the realtime api in your controller but currently that's in limited beta.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/